# HTML5 Canvas scroll lag

Tags: html, canvas, smooth-scrolling

I'm making an HTML5 canvas platformer game. The player's view (the camera) is updated every frame after the player's position is updated. This is causing the camera to be slightly jerky (if you look at the leftmost side of the camera outline). I can't have the camera position be choppy like that.

Question: How can I fix the camera so it's position is updated with the player's but so it's smooth? (Seamless moving, not choppy, not laggy)

```js
//setting everything up.
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
 wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
 requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame,
 then = Date.now(),
 now,
 framesPerSecond = 30,
 counter = 1000/framesPerSecond,
 delta = 0,
 //for smooth movement.
 friction = 0.9,
 //to track key presses.
 keyDown = {};

var main = function(){
 now = Date.now();
 delta += now - then;
 then = now;

 if(delta >= counter){
  delta = 0;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  tick();
  render();
 }

 requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

var player = {
 x:0,
 y:115,
 w:20,
 h:20,
 velX:0,
 speed:3,
 color:"maroon",
 camX:0,
 camY:0,
 camOffsetX:250,
 camOffsetY:125,

 tick:function(){
  this.velX *= friction
  this.x += 2*this.velX;

  //left arrow key.
  if(37 in keyDown){
   if(this.velX > -this.speed){
    this.velX--;
   }
  }

  //right arrow key.
  if(39 in keyDown){
   if(this.velX < this.speed){
    this.velX++;
   }
  }

  //update new camera position after the player's position got updated.
  this.updateCamera();
 },

 render:function(){
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
 },

 updateCamera:function(){
  //sets the center of the camera view to the center of the player
  this.camX = this.x + this.w/2 - this.camOffsetX;
  this.camY = this.y + this.h/2 - this.camOffsetY;
  //scrolls canvas with the camera
  wrapper.scrollLeft = this.camX;
 }
};

var tick = function(){
 player.tick();
}

var render = function(){
 player.render();
  
  //arrow pointing to the problem
  ctx.fillText("<---", player.camX + 10, player.y);

 //camera bounderies
 ctx.strokeRect(player.x + player.w/2 - player.camOffsetX, player.y + player.h/2 - player.camOffsetY, 2*player.camOffsetX, 2*player.camOffsetY);
  
 //sets markers so you can tell your're scrolling.
 ctx.fillText("250 pixels", 250, 10);
 ctx.fillText("500 pixels", 500, 10);
 ctx.fillText("750 pixels", 750, 10);
 ctx.fillText("1000 pixels", 1000, 10);
 ctx.fillText("1250 pixels", 1250, 10);
 ctx.fillText("1500 pixels", 1500, 10);
 ctx.fillText("1750 pixels", 1750, 10);
}

//adds or removes keys from keyDown on keydown or keyup
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
 keyDown[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
 delete keyDown[e.keyCode];
});

requestAnimationFrame(main);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid navy;
}
```

```html
<!-- div is so the canvas can scroll. -->
<div id="wrapper" style="width:500px; height:250px; border:1px solid navy; overflow:hidden;">
 <canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="250"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are using the canvas. You should not create a canvas larger than can be displayed on the screen. You just overwork your rendering code if you do.

The flickering is due to you trying to fit the canvas pixels at fractions of a pixel. If you set the camera position to x = 100.5 pixel the display can not physically move the display pixels by 1/2 so it does its best to interpolate the canvas pixels to fit the display pixels. The result is flickering.

But you should not be moving the canvas, rather you should move the canvas transform. This ensures that the bounding rectangle is always aligned with the display pixels, even when you scroll fractions of a pixel.

I have made some changes to your code. inside the `main` function I have changed the canvas transform to follow the camera rather than move canvas in the DOM.

```js
//adds or removes keys from keyDown on keydown or keyup
function keyEvent(e) {
  keyDown[e.keyCode] = e.type === "keydown"
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyEvent);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyEvent);

requestAnimationFrame(main);
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var then;
const framesPerSecond = 30;
var counter = 1000 / framesPerSecond;
var delta = 0;
var friction = 0.9;
const keyDown = {};

function main(time) {
  if (then === undefined) {
    then = time
  }
  delta += time - then;
  then = time;

  if (delta >= counter) {
    delta = 0;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // set default transform
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    player.update();

    // set the view to the camera
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -player.camX, -player.camY);
    render();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

var player = {
  x: 0,
  y: 115,
  w: 20,
  h: 20,
  velX: 0,
  speed: 3,
  color: "maroon",
  camX: 0,
  camY: 0,
  camOffsetX: 250,
  camOffsetY: 125,

  update() {
    this.velX *= friction
    this.x += 2 * this.velX;
    if (keyDown["37"]) {
      if (this.velX > -this.speed) {
        this.velX--
      }
    }
    if (keyDown["39"]) {
      if (this.velX < this.speed) {
        this.velX++
      }
    }
    this.updateCamera();
  },
  render() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  },
  updateCamera() {
    this.camX = this.x + this.w / 2 - this.camOffsetX;
    this.camY = this.y + this.h / 2 - this.camOffsetY;
  }
};


var render = function() {
  player.render();

  //arrow pointing to the problem
  ctx.fillText("<---", player.camX + 10, player.y);
  ctx.fillText("Player X pos : " + player.camX.toFixed(3), player.x, 100);

  //camera bounderies
  ctx.strokeRect(player.x + player.w / 2 - player.camOffsetX, player.y + player.h / 2 - player.camOffsetY, 2 * player.camOffsetX, 2 * player.camOffsetY);

  //sets markers so you can tell your're scrolling.
  ctx.fillText("250 pixels", 250, 10);
  ctx.fillText("500 pixels", 500, 10);
  ctx.fillText("750 pixels", 750, 10);
  ctx.fillText("1000 pixels", 1000, 10);
  ctx.fillText("1250 pixels", 1250, 10);
  ctx.fillText("1500 pixels", 1500, 10);
  ctx.fillText("1750 pixels", 1750, 10);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<!-- div is so the canvas can scroll. -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! In short, the code works. I'm wondering if you can explain a little more why transforming it `-player.camX` and `-player.camY` makes it work. Can you edit your answer to explain that?

Comment: @Jordan because when you move the canvas as you were doing you were moving it fractions of a pixel, this does not match the display pixel alignment. When you move the transform you move the origin to align to the top left canvas pixel. this ensures that the view is always aligned with the display pixels.